# Is possible to manipulate Envrionment Variables on the browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I've created React App and I want to get different output depends on the environment variable that is on .env file. There is no problem until this part.

So my question is, is there any way to manipulate environment variables on the browser?

Comment: in one word - no

Comment: What's the use case? You shouldn't be changing the environment variables once they're defined by whatever environment the app is running in

Comment: I don't want to change these variables, just I have got a concern about the vulnerability.

Comment: @Mert: Then you should have phrased it as a security question rather than a "how can I ..." question.